# Overriding Equals on IEquatable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following method which I am trying to use to stop people altering the `querystring` in order to view other peoples details:

```
public static bool IsCurrentUserAuthorisedVessel(HttpRequest request)
{
    Guid currentUser = GetCurrentUserId();
    PersonRepository repo = new PersonRepository();
    VesselRepository vesselRepo = new VesselRepository();

    Person currentPerson = repo.GetPersonByUser(currentUser);
    int qs = int.Parse(request.QueryString["VesselId"]);
    Vessel currentVessel = vesselRepo.GetVessel(qs);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString["VesselId"]))
    {       
        if (IsCurrentUserAdmin())
        {
            return true;  //Always return true for admin                  
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentPerson.Vessels.Contains(currentVessel))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }                
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the example I am currently debugging `currentPerson.Vessels` yields 3 vessels in an `Icollection<Vessel>` one of which has a `VesselId` of 6 which also happens to be the VesselId of `currentVessel` however the match is failing and the method is returning `false`.

I have done some reading on similar SO questions and MSDN documentation and my understanding of what is happening here is because the Vessel which has an ID of 6 within the ICollection is a different instance of the currentVessel I am attempting to match, the reference is resulting in not equal and something to do with the equality rules are not based on ID.

My `Person` model contains `public virtual ICollection<Vessel> Vessels { get; set; }` does this mean that I must implement the `IEquatable` interface on my `Vessel` model and then override the Equals method.

I want my own custom rules based on id for equality in this instance. How do I override this method?

Comment: Please add the tag of the ORM (Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc) you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding `Equals` in this situation seems a little overkill here, why not just do

```
currentPerson.Vessels.Any(x => x.ID == currentVessel.ID)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I feel like an idiot now. Easy when you know how hey!

Answer (score 2):

The solution suggested by @james is not the best practice. 
here why if you have a long list of Vessels  that should be added  to a `Hashset<Vessel>`  contains  method  will cost only `O(1)` since it  will be indexed on `GetHashCode` while  `.Any` is an extension method that should iterate through all elements to find the right one and the cost will be `O(n)`

you could  do something like  this

```
public class Vessel : IEquatable<Vessel>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Vessel other)
        {
            return Id == other.Id ; 
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var vessel = obj as Vessel;
            return vessel != null && vessel.Id == this.Id;
        }
    }
```

**Update**

the reasons why I have stated it's not a best practice it's that OP stated that he has an `ICollection<Vessel>`  which can be converted to many Generics collections like `List<T>` for example.

from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx)

When the search methods of a number of generic collection objects are called. Some of these types and their methods include the following:

- Some of the generic overloads of the BinarySearch method.
- The search methods of the List class, including List.Contains(T), List.IndexOf, List.LastIndexOf, and List.Remove.
- The search methods of the Dictionary class, including ContainsKey and Remove.
  The search methods of the generic LinkedList class, including LinkedList.Contains and Remove.

Comment: Simplify the typed equals to: `return Id == other.Id` and the object equals return to `return vessel != null && Equals(vessel)`. Less code and you don't duplicate the logic.

Comment: To claim the use of `Any` here is "*not a good solution*" or "*not best practise*" is nonsensical. The argument *for* implementing `Equals` is certainly valid, but only *if* performance / list size is a factor - which the OP has not mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if (currentPerson.Vessels.Contains(currentVessel))
{
    return true;
}
else
    return false;
```

to

```
return currentPerson.Vessels.Any(x => x.ID == currentVessel.ID)
```